# Why does the Vim substitute command `:s/\([a-zA-Z]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\2/g` not remove all space on the line `a b c d`

Tags: regex, vim

Suppose that I have a line:
`a b c d`
When I execute the substitute command `:s/\([a-zA-Z]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\2/g` on the line, it only remove two spaces, the result is:
`ab cd`
Why it doesn't remove all the space?

Comment: Because the last `\([a-zA-Z]\)` is a *consuming* subpattern. Do you need to get `abcd`? Then try `:s/\([a-zA-Z]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)\@=/\1/g`

Comment: Yes, but I find it can't remove all the spaces. Does *consuming* subpattern mean that it will not be matched by the next pattern?

Comment: Consuming means the text matched with the subpattern is a part of the match. The next match can only repeat after the preceding match, so, the first `[a-zA-Z]` will not be able to match `b` as it is matched during the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have got the cause of the problem, and got the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you get is expected because the last `\([a-zA-Z]\)` is a *consuming*  subpattern.

*Consuming* means the text matched with the subpattern is a part of the match. The next match can only start after the preceding match, so, the first `[a-zA-Z]` will not be able to match `b` as it is matched during the first iteration.

To get `abcd`, use `:s/\([a-zA-Z]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)\@=/\1/g` where `\(...\)\@=` is a "lookahead" construct.

Answer (score 1):

I would do with the handy `\zs \ze`:

```
s/[a-zA-Z]\zs \ze[a-zA-Z]//g
```

does the job. And easier to read.

The different is, this line matches only space(s), instead of `[a-zA-Z]s`. So you don't have to do look-around thing or group referencing.